# AVFoundation and video

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to use AVFoundation, AVPlayer and AVPlayerViewController to show a video. Does anyone know of any good tutorials out there that does NOT use MPMoviePlayer?

Please let m eknow!

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## AVPlayerViewController

**AVPlayerViewController** is the **AVKit** ViewController that hides away most of the complexity involved with dealing directly with **AVFoundation**. Its very simple and intuitive, if you check the [AVPlayerViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/) you will notice that it does not hold that many properties, if you want to initialise one and attribute a video to it, you have three options ( that I can recall ).

1. Initialise it in code and set the frame of it;
2. Subclass it and call it when you wanna use it;
3. Use Storyboards / nibs to allocate a **AVKit Player View Controller**.

Either way its up to you and this is a common pattern among iOS developers, so it shouldn't strike as a surprise to you unless you are a complete beginner. Please note that for any of these ways of creating an [AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/), you have to initialise the [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html) object with an [AVPlayerItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html) or an URL carrying the video you want to display.

#### Subclassing AVPlayerViewController-Swift

**Obs.** This is the swift example, but the Objective-C one follows the same pattern, the only change is the syntax of each language.

```
class AVKitPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // get the video URL
        let videoURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Test", withExtension: ".mov")

        // Initialise with URL
        player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)

        // Initialise with AVPlayerItem
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: videoURL!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

        // If you want custom controls showsPlaybackControls should be false
        // Then you must create your own buttons
        //showsPlaybackControls = false 
    }
}
```

## AVFoundation

AVFoundation is a very large and interesting framework, you can do a lot of advanced and interesting stuff with it. I would encourage you to go read the docs and checkout these **WWDC-2015** sample code:

- [AVFoundationPiPPlayer: Picture-in-Picture Playback with AVKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AVFoundationPiPPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [AVFoundationQueuePlayer-iOS: Using a Mixture of Local File Based Assets and HTTP Live Streaming Assets with AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AVFoundationQueuePlayer-iOS/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS: Using AVFoundation to Play Media](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS/Introduction/Intro.html)

#### AVFoundation Programming Guide

- [AVFoundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/AVFoundationPG.pdf)

I hope this helps you. Happy Coding. :smile: